# Jquery toggleClass loses the class once links is clicked or page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, toggleclass

When the link is not pointing to anywhere (href="#") my toggleClass works as it is suppose to. But as soon as I fill in the "href" with an URL it doesnt work anymore. I suspect it is because the page is refreshed? But I'm quite new to JS. If this is the problem how can I work around it? and if it's not, then what have I done wrong?

So this is my current javascript using jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.button').click(function()
    { 
        $('.buttonselected').removeClass('buttonselected');
        $(this).toggleClass('buttonselected'); 
    }); 
});
```

And this is my HTML code:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li> 
            <a class="button" href="?page=frontpage"> HOME </a> 
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

- There are more links in the list, but that is irrelevant for this question.
- Yes, I'm using PHP include.
- Also, how can I set a link to "toggleClass" when the page loads so that it gets        that class when someone first enters the website.
- Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use event.preventDefault()

```
$('.button').click(function( event )
{ 
    event.preventDefault(); // default action of the event will not be triggered.

    $('.buttonselected').removeClass('buttonselected');
    $(this).toggleClass('buttonselected'); 
});
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to load your frontpage (as in your link) and give it a "buttonselected" class
than you need to use PHP.

Something like this

```
if( isset($_POST['page']) ){
    $selectedPage = $_POST['page'];
}
```

View

```
<a class="button <?php echo ($selectedPage=='frontpage')?' buttonselected':'' ?>" href="?page=frontpage"> HOME </a>
```

Comment: Yes, this works. But then the link itself doesn't trigger. I want the effect that this "event" gives me, but with the link working. I'm using query string and php on my page.

Comment: Initially I did this with PHP, but it looked messy so I removed it. I thought for sure jQuery would be an easy fix for it and look cleaner. Guess not..

Comment: Do it with jquery $.ajax call in the click event without reloading the page, much more elegant and clean

Comment: I did it with ajax, jquery and php. And now it works fine, but a new problem has occurred. Whenever I refresh the site, the button loses it's .toggleClass information and when I click on the "home" button to return to the frontpage the opposite happens. The previous button that had the toggleClass information keeps it. Any idea how I can work around this? Sorry if my explanation is bad.

Comment: On page reload you need PHP or after page loaded you can parse url and look for 'page' param and set the class (but I would not do this). Anyway you need to work with url 'page' param either frontend or backend

Comment: I found a solution for it based on the .click event. It was actually not that hard once I saw how it could be done. Thanks for all the help and the initial response. It was very much needed at the time.

Answer (score 2):

You are right. The class goes away because the page is reloaded. If you need a specific link to have a specific class when the page loads, you'll need to hard code something to that link. Either manually put the class on the link with php or distinguish it in some other way so that JavaScript can find it.

If the link that should have the class is *different* based on which link you clicked previously, you will have to use a cookie or the [localStorage object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage) to retain that information.

Better yet, you should try to figure out a way to pass this information around that doesn't involve reloading the page. That would be ideal as, in most cases, users don't like to have a page reload on them when they're not expecting it.

EDIT:

The answer by @pszaba is great if you don't need to utilize query string variables.

Comment: That would be ideal, yes. And I really don't need to reload the whole page every time anyway. Any idea where I can start? Information about how to do that?

Comment: I might be able to help with that.  Can you give me a clearer picture of what you want your application to do and what the information in the query string is used for?

Comment: Deleted that comment. Yes, I'll give you some more information. Just let me think about how I can write it down in an informative and logical way. I'll get back to you on it.

Comment: Basically I got a page called index.php where I use include to get all my different pages and put them into one. The layout of the page; header, aside, nav and footer stay the same throughout. But the index.php also contain a "content" page, and this is the only page that changes information for every time the website is refreshed, or button pressed if you may. All I want my buttons to do is change to a spesific CSS style when the user is on the page that the button links to. So that when a spesific content page is shown that same button which links to that content page get's it's own style.

Comment: But if as you say I could make a site where only the "content" page is refreshed that would be great. How would I go about doing this? Where can I learn about the coding required to do it?

Comment: As @pszaba said, you should look into [jQuery's .ajax method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Instead of using the href attribute, use a click event to trigger an ajax function. When the new content is loaded, a callback function will run and you can use it to repopulate the html in that section.

Comment: So this problem is solved now. My final result was a mix of javascript and php using jquery and ajax. In the end it ended up pretty nice and the code looks alright. I did manage to create an Ajax function so that only the "content page" is refreshed. Good idea. Thanks again for the help.